# Page tab redirecting to page tab URL, but only for some users

Tags: facebook, redirect

I have a PageTab configured to serve content from my own web server (within an iframe).

The script on my web server just gets the signed_request variable (passed from Facebook), and checks to see if a user has liked the page or not, and displays content accordingly. This is working for MOST users, but some users are reporting that Facebook is redirecting their browsers directly to the URL that the page tab points to (the URL on my web server).

I have put debug in place, and sure enough, users are accessing the URL directly. Not cool.

This is purely a PageTab, nothing to do with Canvas at all. Anyone have any ideas why this would be happening?

Comment: Kindly paste the code where you are checking the user likes and redirection, please specify the language you are using, if this is the case for only some user you can double check if user likes the page or not, like suppose user has been redirected to a page without liking your app/page then on that page you can check it again, not in signed_request but you can make call to graph api and check if user likes your page if not redirect back to the previous page. I hope you got the point.